# How to sum the largest two elements in an array

Tags: ruby

What is the appropriate method to get the sum of the two largest values in array using Ruby?

I know `array.sort` and `array.max` and `inject(:+)` but I don't know how to combine them.

Comment: When asking it's important to show the effort toward solving the problem, otherwise it looks like you want us to write code for you. Read "[ask]" including the linked pages and “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421)”. It's also important to select the answer that solved the problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 6):

I would strongly favor the simpler and faster:

```
array.max(2).reduce(:+)
```

Sorting is unnecessary, it is enough to scan the array updating a max-heap of size K. Using `Array#max(K)` you achieve O(N x log(K)) asymptotic time complexity versus O(N x log(N)) of sorting.

Comment: Excellent use of `max`.

Comment: `array.max(2).sum` is shorter

Comment: It's shorter in length. It's pretty much a wash speed-wise until you get into BIG arrays or loop several thousand times. Fruity says it's "similar".

Answer (score 4):

```
[9, 4, 5, 1].sort.last(2).sum
=> 14
```

Comment: Cool. Didn't know about last with arguments. `sum` though is a Rails method. He marked question as RoR, but asked a Ruby solution. Not clear does he need a vanilla solution.

Comment: I added benchmarks to test the various solutions. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38809082/128421

Comment: Ruby will get `Enumerable#sum` in [version 2.4](http://www.blackbytes.info/ruby-version-changes/).

Answer (score 2):

```
[1,2,3,4].sort[-2..-1].inject(:+)
```

If you are looking for a more efficient solution, you will be better with this one:

```
[1,2,3,4].inject([0, 0]) do |largest, el|
  if largest[0] < el
    largest[1] = largest[0]
    largest[0]  = el
  elsif largest[1] < el
    largest[1] = el
  end
  largest
end.inject(:+)
```

If you are familiar with algorithm complexity, than you can see that the first one is `nlogn` to `n^2`, depending on the Ruby sorting algorithm, where the second solution is just `n` as it goes through the array once.

Comment: "efficient" isn't a good word to describe the difference. The first is shorter, clear and easy to understand, and runs about 50x faster than the second. It's also idiomatic Ruby when trying to do this task.

Comment: Further to @theTinMan's point, asymtotic comparisons are often irrelevent. You need to test. In particular, when one method is optimized in C (e.g. `sort`) and the other is not, the former is often the faster, sometimes by a mile.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

```
array = [13, 2, 21, 36, 4, 9]

array.reverse.first(2).reduce(:+)
```

In this method we are reverse sorting the array, which is sorting it from highest to lowest. This puts the largest numbers first in the array. `reduce` method returns the sum of these numbers. In this case, the sum of 36 and 21 is 57.

```
57
```

Comment: Since this is a Rails question, `sum` would be preferred over `reduce(:+)`.

Comment: `array.reverse.first(2).reduce(:+) # => 13`. You're not sorting the array at all. It's always good to check your work.

Answer (score 1):

It's always good to have some benchmarks to see what is the fastest way to accomplish something:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/enumerable'
require 'fruity'

ARRAY = (0..1000).to_a.shuffle

compare do

  adriano { ARRAY.max(2).reduce(:+)       }
  mori    { ARRAY.sort.last(2).sum        }
  edgars  { ARRAY.sort[-2..-1].inject(:+) }

end


# >> Running each test 64 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> adriano is faster than edgars by 50.0% ± 10.0%
# >> edgars is similar to mori
```