# How to quickly multiply the two largest array elements

Tags: arrays, ruby, performance, methods

I am doing a challenge which asks for a method to multiply the two largest elements of an array and find a solution that takes under one second.

This is what I currently have at ~1.6 seconds

```
def max_product(a)
  a.sort[-1] * a.sort[-2]
end
```

How can I rewrite this in order to speed it up?

Comment: Here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350524/ruby-method-sum-of-largest-2-elements-in-array

Answer (score 5):

```
a = [3,4,2,5,2,6]

def max_product(a)
  a.max(2).reduce(:*)
end

max_product(a)
  #=> 30
```

[Enumerable#max](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) was permitted to have an argument in Ruby v.2.2. Same for `min`, `max_by` and `min_by`.

Note that `Enumerable#max` will benefit from performance improvements in the forthcoming Ruby v2.4.

Let's compare this with just sorting and taking the last two values, and also with a roll-your-own, as @ZbyszekKr suggests.

```
def max_product_sort(a)
  a.sort.last(2).inject(:*)
end

def max_product_sort!(a)
  a.sort!
  a[-2] * a[-1]
end

def max_product_rolled(arr)
  m1 = arr.max
  max_loc = arr.index(m1)
  arr[max_loc] = arr[0,2].min - 1
  m2 = arr.max
  arr[max_loc] = m1 # to avoid mutating arr
  m1 * m2
end
```

First let's compare using the `fruity` gem.

```
require 'fruity'

arr = 1_000_000.times.map { rand 2_000_000 }
arr1 = arr.dup
arr2 = arr.dup
arr3 = arr.dup
arr4 = arr.dup

compare(
  max_2:  -> { max_product(arr1) },
  rolled: -> { max_product_rolled(arr2) },
  sort:   -> { max_product_sort(arr3) },
  sort!:  -> { max_product_sort!(arr4) }
)
Running each test once. Test will take about 8 seconds.
sort! is faster than max_2 by 4x ± 0.1
max_2 is faster than rolled by 2x ± 0.1
rolled is faster than sort by 2.1x ± 0.1
```

Next compare using `benchmark`.

```
arr = 1_000_000.times.map { rand 2_000_000 }
arr1 = arr.dup
arr2 = arr.dup
arr3 = arr.dup
arr4 = arr.dup

require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("max_2")  { max_product(arr1) }
  x.report("rolled") { max_product_rolled(arr2) }
  x.report("sort")   { max_product_sort(arr3) }
  x.report("sort!")  { max_product_sort!(arr4) }
end

          user      system     total       real
max_2   0.060000   0.010000   0.070000 (  0.066777)
rolled  0.110000   0.000000   0.110000 (  0.111191)
sort    0.210000   0.000000   0.210000 (  0.218155)
sort!   0.210000   0.010000   0.220000 (  0.214664)
```

Lastly, let's try `benchmark` with a warm-up. We cannot include `sort !` in this test, as the array will be sorted in place in the warmup, making it super-fast in the test that counts.

```
arr = 1_000_000.times.map { rand 2_000_000 }
arr1 = arr.dup
arr2 = arr.dup
arr3 = arr.dup

Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report("max_2")  { max_product(arr1) }
  x.report("rolled") { max_product_rolled(arr2) }
  x.report("sort")   { max_product_sort(arr3) }
end

Rehearsal ------------------------------------------
max_2    0.060000   0.000000   0.060000 (  0.066969)
rolled   0.110000   0.000000   0.110000 (  0.117527)
sort     0.210000   0.020000   0.230000 (  0.244783)
--------------------------------- total: 0.400000sec

             user     system      total        real
max_2    0.050000   0.000000   0.050000 (  0.059948)
rolled   0.100000   0.000000   0.100000 (  0.106099)
sort     0.200000   0.000000   0.200000 (  0.219202)
```

As you see, the `benchmark` results differ from those obtained using `fruity` in that `sort!`, which is last in `benchmark`, is first in `fruity`. I think I know why `sort!` looks so good in `fruity`. `fruity`'s [github page](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity) states, "We first determine the number of inner iterations needed to get a meaningful clock measurement..." I suspect that, for `sort!`, this initial step mutates `arr4`, skewing the results of the reported test that follows.

For what it's worth, the `benchmark` results are what I expected (except for `sort` being slightly faster than `sort!`.

Comment: This is probably the best solution. Other relay on sorting the array which is  O(n*log(n)). This algorithm has a chance of working in linear time.

Comment: Might be that max is implemented with sorting which is a bit underwhelming. You could always do a linear search yourself.

Comment: Shouldn't you be cloning `arr` before benchmarking? Otherwise you risk changing the results since the sort is being done in-place.

Comment: Okay, now you're definitely messing with the results by doing `sort!` prior to testing `sort` on the same array.

Comment: @pjs, I noticed that when editing, but rather than cloning I decided to change the max value to a value that was smaller than the two largest values, obtained the max again and then restored the original alerted max value to avoid mutating the array.

Comment: @pjs, egad! Thank, I'll fix it. Strangely, the results don't change.

Comment: As @pjs said, you need to `dup` the array. By doing `arr.dup` instead of `arr` as the parameter,`max_2` is 2x the next fastest. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38809082/128421

Comment: @theTinMan, isn't it sufficient to have `sort!` at the end of `compare`? I also tried it with each method having the argument `arr.dup` rather than `arr` (after refreshing `arr`) and the result was just the opposite of what I reported, with `max_2` being the clear winner. I must be overlooking something obvious. Can you explain why?

Comment: I wouldn't do it using `arr.dup` as an argument, because then you're rolling the cost of `dup` into the cost of the algorithm.  I prefer to `dup` beforehand so the benchmark is working with pristine identical inputs and only the algorithm is being timed.  I'm stymied by what you're reporting, though!

Comment: Using `dup` is adding it equally to all, so it's a `nop` at the end. It's OK to add the same operation equally, just don't do it to one only.

Comment: If I remember right, you can't count on the order that the tests occur. The author (@Marc-AndréLafortune) would be the best authority on that; He does lurk here periodically, so maybe he'll drop in and clarify.

Comment: @theTinMan, good to know. I posted more results and am still scratching my head.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune, according to the Tin Man you authored the fruity gem. Can you explain my results?

Comment: @CarySwoveland `benchmark` results are more in line with what I expected, with `max_2` dominating and `sort` vs `sort!` pretty much tied.  What happens if you use `bmbm` to give it a warm-up?